# Prevent decompiling android apk

Tags: android, security

I'm creating an app for android and ios, and i already know that it's theoretically possible to decompile an android app. The app contains sensitive information that i don't want users to have access to as the app interfaces with a webserver. If a user gained access to some information available in the source code, they could potentially spam my web server with requests.

Is there any way to authenticate a connection between the app and the server, assuming that the source code is accessible, or is there any way to obfuscate my code to prevent a malicious user from spamming my webserver.

Thankss

Comment: Check out this article. It somehow gives a good approach to have some security when requesting a server https://medium.com/@rezabigdeli6/how-to-send-a-semi-secure-request-to-a-server-in-android-359b11b4e873#.q83vstxvk

Answer (score 21, accepted):

***[UPDATE]***

**

When you build your application using Android gradle plugin version > 3.4.0, the plugin chooses R8 to optimize and obfuscate the code. The rules can now be configured on proguard-rules.pro or proguard-app.conf files. the rules to indicate what to exclude from the obfuscation are similar to the ones in proguard.cfg used earlier.

You can import your proguard files in your build.gradle like

> ```
> buildTypes{
>   ...
>   release{
>       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
>                 'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
>                 'proguard-rules.pro'
>   }
> }
> ```

[R8](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#configuration-files) picks up all the existing proguard rules files as long as they're included in the build.gradle. You can also [configure](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#add-configuration) what pieces to obfuscate for different product flavors that you may have.

**

***[OLD BUT RELEVANT INFO]***

[Proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) is a tool that will help you obfusate your code. This comes as part of your android tools and you just need to activate it. [This](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/proguard-android-and-licensing-server.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20blogspot/hsDu%20%28Android%20Developers%20Blog%29) link and [this](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#) will help further.

Proguard's default configuration (in proguard.cfg) will be enough to sufficiently obfuscate your code. However you might want to tweak your proguard configuration when you have methods/classes that are being dynamically accessed.

1. For instance, accessing classes/methods with Reflection will need you to have the code to be intact. You might sometimes experience ClassNotFoundException if proguard obfuscates it.
2. If you have classes that are being accessed in the AndroidManifest/ Layout Files, you should prevent proguard from obfuscating them.

This can be done by adding

```
-keep public class <MyPackage.MyClass>
```

to your proguard.cfg.

**

While Proguard makes static analysis harder, DexGuard protects from both static and dynamic analysis. [DexGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/blog/dexguard-vs-proguard) is specifially for android applications and is only commercially available while Proguard is open source and is for any java bytecode obfuscation / optimization.

Comment: AFAIK Proguard basically renames methods and other parts of code so it is realy hard to read it but it doesnt prevent anyone from decompiling your app.

Comment: @Siddharth N i want to hide my all activities name when some on try to decompile  the apk

Answer (score 12):

You cannot prevent decompiling android apk, you can just increase the difficulty of decompilation, proguard is the best option.

Comment: Proguard is far from the best option if you want to make it difficult to decompile your application. There exists plenty of packers that protect the intellectual property. Examples can be Ijiami, apkprotect, Bangcle etc. These packers have anti reversing, anti debugging, anti vm etc. They are commercial tools however. They utilize runtime decryption and unpacking of important functionality, which makes it very difficult to decompile anything unless you have experience in unpacking etc.

Answer (score 6):

DexGuard provides even better security then ProGuard but it is NOT free: https://www.saikoa.com/dexguard

DexGuard can even obfuscate String constants.