# Androidmanifest.xml is unwritable

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm new here, and I don't know if this has been asked before.
I want to edit an apk, so I downloaded Android Studio, but when I tried to edit the file, it says "File is read-only". I'm trying to change the SDK version part. On my mac, I changed the permissions of the APK file for everyone to read and write. How can I make it writable? Or, is there another way to edit the minimum SDK version and the target SDK version?

[image: Error message I got]

I just want to change the minimum to 19 and the target to 14.

Thanks.

Comment: how you are editing an apk ?

Comment: Remove uses-sdk.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible at all to edit an apk file. And btw, you should never set minSdkVersion higher than the targetSdkVersion. The rule is: compileSdkVersion >= targetSdkVersion >= minSdkVersion.

Comment: Did you open the apk to be edited in Android Studio using App Analyzer ?

Comment: Firstly if you just created the project then you probably opened a generated Manifest file, secondly you should change the versions in the gradle file, lastly you just said you want to change the minimum to be 19 and the target to be 14, Target cannot be lower than the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you have decompiled the apk. and You can't edit the code because developer has added pro-guard rules for the apk because if anyone try's to decompile
it then it will show nothing and u can't update any code.

Comment: The fact that he cant edit the Manifest in an **apk** file has nothing to do with the pro-guard rules.

Comment: so how you can stop your apk from decompiling ?

Comment: i think this is the answer "You cannot prevent decompiling android apk, you can just increase the difficulty of decompilation, proguard is the best option."   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21199427/prevent-decompiling-android-apk